# Parsing XML with Android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I'm developing an Android 2.2 application.

I have the following XML file on res/xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<data>
    <turo>
        <name>Rodo</name>
        <latitude>37.212123</latitude>
        <longitude>0.1231231</longitude>
    </turo>
</data>
```

I'm getting crazy because I can't find an example to see how can I parse this file.

I also have the following class to store data retrieved:

```
public class Turo{
    private String name;
    private Location location;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Turo(String name){
        setName(name);
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
}
```

This my method to parse it (it's incompleted):

```
public Vector<Turo> getTurosFromXML(Activity activity, int xmlId) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    Resources res = activity.getResources();

    XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(xmlId);
    xpp.next();
    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
    {
...
    }
}
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example:

```
package com.exercise.AndroidXmlResource;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.XmlResourceParser;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidXmlResource extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView myXmlContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_xml);
    String stringXmlContent;
    try {
        stringXmlContent = getEventsFromAnXML(this);
        myXmlContent.setText(stringXmlContent);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String getEventsFromAnXML(Activity activity) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    Resources res = activity.getResources();
    XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.myxml);
    xpp.next();
    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
         if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
              stringBuffer.append("--- Start XML ---");
         } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
             stringBuffer.append("\nSTART_TAG: "+xpp.getName());
         } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
             stringBuffer.append("\nEND_TAG: "+xpp.getName());
         } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
             stringBuffer.append("\nTEXT: "+xpp.getText());
         }
         eventType = xpp.next();
   }
   stringBuffer.append("\n--- End XML ---");
   return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

}

The Android UI XML file would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/my_xml" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the `XML` parsed in this example is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rootelement1>
    <subelement>
         Hello XML Sub-Element 1
    </subelement>
    <subelement>
         Hello XML Sub-Element 2
         <subsubelement>Sub Sub Element</subsubelement>
    </subelement>
</rootelement1>
```

NOTE: Info extracted from `Android-er`